# How is that ensemble Free energy is lower than the MFE in RNAfold from ViennaRNA

Tags: rna, rna-structure, thermodynamics

In the [tutorial](https://www.tbi.univie.ac.at/RNA/tutorial/) of RNAfold it states,

`RNAfold` reads RNA sequences from stdin, calculates their minimum free energy (MFE) structure, prints the MFE structure in dot-bracket notation and its free energy to stdout.

In the example using the `-p --MEA` options, the

- **MFE = -5.00** and the
- **ensemble Free Energy = -5.72**.

How can the free energy of the ensemble be lower than the minimum free energy?

Comment: @MichaelG. First, thank you. I read and learn from your comments and answers. Second: I tried with __CUACGGCGCGGCGC__ and I get: structure=.....(((...))) with -0.40 kcal/mol for the MFE and for the probab. representation of the ensemble, structu=.....,,,...)), with -1.10 kcal/mol. 
I don't see pseudoknots there (should I?).

Comment: @MichaelG. 1st: Thank you! I feel honored!! 2nd: I think (and I could be wrong) that the only tool in Vienna that predicts pseudoknots is RNAPKplex (I am too far from being expert in the topic, I just googled it -couldn't find that info as fast in Vienna documentation-).  3rd: I am perplexed... I don't know how is this possible